# jQuery: "Pushup" script modification

Tags: jquery

In an effort to have our visitors upgrade their browsers, we are using the Pushup script. If you're not familiar with it, you can check it out here: http://www.pushuptheweb.com

However, we're using the ported jQuery version of that script.

Implementation is simple, but I've been requested to make a change that's over my head, that's why I'm here.

As you can see, the script has basically 2 types of messages:

1. The ***"Upgrade"*** message
2. The ***"Remind Me Later"*** message.

I need to add a 3rd message: A ***"Don't Show Again"*** message.

The ideas with each of the messages are:

- ***Upgrade*** message: Has a click to download the corresponding browser upgrade (already with script).
- ***Remind Me Later*** message: When clicked message goes away for the amount of time specified in the script. If the user closes his browser and reopens it before the specified time has passed, he doesn't see the message again. If he reopens his browser after the time has passed, he'll see the message again. Seems this is controlled by a cookie. (All these features are already in the script).
- ***Don't Show Again*** message: This is the one I need help with. When clicked message goes away forever. I assume a cookie with no expiring date is used for this, or something similar. Message will only appear again if the user deletes his cookies.

The Pushup jQuery project can be found here: https://github.com/stuartloxton/jquery-pushup

I tried to do a fiddle so you could see it but it didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding the 3rd message, which I was actually able to do so, but coding the cookie and do all the things j08691 did in his mod was something I would've never been able to do on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the jquery.pushup.js file and loaded it up at [**http://pastebin.com/a4ZU5U5v**](http://pastebin.com/a4ZU5U5v). I just modified the script to add the text "Don't Show Again" which when clicked will set a cookie to expire in about 14 years (feel free to change). Let me know if that doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Hey j08691, your solution was **exactly** what we needed. Thanks a million for your help. I'm studying your modifications to see what I can learn from them. Wish I could give you more points for providing this great solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the built in `Pushup.setReminder(hours);` option?

Set it to 8760 and your user won't be reminded for a year.

You can also change the reminder.message default `message: 'Remind me again in #{hours}'` to something like `message: 'Don't remind me'`

This avoids having to change their code at all.

Comment: Good points Paul. I think that with j08691's mod this script is now way more robust. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Understood. Make sure to remember to incorporate your changes to their code if you (or anyone else in your company) ever has to update the plugin.